# Mechanize download file with changing URL

Tags: python, mechanize

Hi I've got this code working to download a file however the file name after 'ID' changes value how can I get the script to recognise this?

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('https://google.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['clientUsername'] = 'companyname'
br.form['username'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password'
sub = br.submit()
print sub.geturl()

br.retrieve('https://www.google.com/examplefileID=', 'testfile.csv') [0]
```

Comment: Do you know what the file name will be ahead of time or is there somewhere you can infer the filename?

Comment: Hi Clay, thanks for the quick response!

The file name looks like this 'properties_01-11-2018_12-50-55.csv' it gets stamped with a date and time at the point of requesting the download.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your comment clarifying the filename, it looks like you can use the builtin [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) Python module to get the date and time right before you make the request. Something like this should get you what you want:

```
import mechanize
import datetime

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open('https://google.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['clientUsername'] = 'companyname'
br.form['username'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password'
sub = br.submit()
print sub.geturl()

# Generate a filename based off a date and time stamp
# use datetime.now() if you don't care about utc
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
filename = 'properties_' + timestamp + '.csv'

br.retrieve('https://www.google.com/examplefileID=', filename) [0]
```

Note. This solution uses UTC, so no timezone, and uses a 24 hour clock format instead of a 12 hour one. If you want a 12 hour format, use `.strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%I_%M_%S')` instead, the `%I` means 12 hour format.